# How to Terminate a Node.js Script with Puppeteer without Closing the Browse

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, browser-automation

I am using Puppeteer with Node.js to automate web scraping tasks. I have set the headless option to false so that I can see the browser window during the script's execution. However, I need to terminate the script gracefully without closing the browser when certain conditions are met.

I have tried using browser.disconnect() is not working and browser.close() closes the browser window, which is not what I want. I have also tried process.stdin.destroy(), but it does not terminate the script as expected.

**MY MAIN MOTIVE**
I try to create a new script that use puppeteer to launch a chromium instance, save the browserWSEndpoint on the file system and exiting the script leaving the browser opened.

So, other puppeteer scripts can connect to this browserWSEndpoint later to speed up it and use the cookies without any other problems.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Here's an example of what I have tried:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  // Perform my automation tasks here
  // ...

  // When certain conditions are met, I want to terminate the script without closing the browser
  process.stdin.on('data', (data) => {
    const input = data.toString().trim();
    if (input === 'exit') {
      process.stdin.removeAllListeners();
      process.stdin.destroy();
      // How can I terminate the script without closing the browser?
      // browser.disconnect() does not disconecnt and does not terminate my script; and browser.close() closes the browser window
      // process.exit(); terminates the script, but also closes the browser window
    }
  });
})();
```

Can someone help me with a solution on how to gracefully terminate the Node.js script with Puppeteer without closing the browser window?